# Jquery - add function to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, slider, slide

Hey there i got this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/5H5Xq/42/

containing this jquery:

```
function anim(selector) {
    $(".images img", selector).first().appendTo($('.images', selector)).fadeOut(2000);  
    $(".images img", selector).first().fadeIn(2000);
}

// Untuk delay gambarnya
var i = 0, max = 3;
myFunction = function(event){
    $(".subbox1").each(function() {anim(this)});
    i += 1;
    if(i >= max) { i = 0; }
}
var interval = setInterval(myFunction, 5000);

$(".slider").hover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    var img = $('<img>'); 
img.attr('src', $(this).attr('data-url'));
    $('#newImage').html(img);
    $('.images').hide();
    return false;
    i += 1;
    $(".subbox1").each(function() {anim(this)});

});

$(".slider").mouseout(
    function (){
        $('.images').show();
       // $('#newImage').hide();
interval =   setInterval(myFunction, 5000);
    }
);
```

It just means:

Every 5 seconds => automatic image-change.

When i hover throw a link => image-change + automatic image change disabled.

What i wanted to add to the automatic image-change:
Depending on the current picture, the

-item gets a new background-color..is this possible?

greetings

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Just change the background-color css attribute of the element depending on your criteria.

```
if (*your criteria here*) {
    element.css("background-color", "#ff0000"); 
}
```

Comment: yea thanks, but i didnt know how to create the criteria, count the setInterval? could you help me a bit? greetings!

Comment: Are you talking about the background color of the image or the link to select the image?

Comment: the link of the selected image*

Comment: It's possible but kind of tough/hacky to do with your code right now since there's no way to map the current image being displayed to a background color. I'd recommend writing an update function that takes in an index of the image to be displayed and in that update function apply the background color change based on the index. Then myFunction only has to increment that value and then call the update function.